# Premature end of script headers: wp-mail.php?

Tags: php, headers, wp-mail

I haven't edited wp-mail.php at all. I'm using the default WordPress file.

I'm trying the whole submit post by email function that we know in settings (using gmail and pop3, if that's relevant).

I try to test it by going to example.com/wp-mail.php

I get an internal server error after a while.

My server logs during this time are:

```
Warning 1.1.1.1 mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds              
Error   1.1.1.1 Premature end of script headers: wp-mail.php
```

I'm using all 1's for my IP address just to show this example.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Post by email does not work by accessing `wp-mail.php`.

You need to go to Settings > Writing on your website and enter POP3 credentials for whatever email address you plan to use. After that, any email you send TO that email address will be parsed and posted.